# I do not understand malloc function

Tags: c, malloc

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int *elements = malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    unsigned long fibs[elements];

    if (argc != 2){
        printf("Usage: %s <# of elements>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }
    compute_fibs (fibs, &elements);

    for (i=0; i<elements; i++) {
        printf ("fibs[%i]: %lu\n",i, fibs[i]);
    }
    printf("Displaying %u fibs\n", elements);
}
```

This is main.c file

and when i compile it gets error

I want to execute this file like ./main 50

and prints 50 Fibonacci values.

so I want to add element(which is in this case 50)

but somehow my malloc() fucntion is not correct(?)

Comment: *and when i compile it gets error* - what kind of error? Also note, this code is incomplete, you might want to read [ask].

Comment: Better to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned int *elements = malloc(2*sizeof(int));
unsigned long fibs[elements];
```

You first allocate room for 2 integers. Now I am not sure what you want to do, but the next line wants to allocate an array on the stack of size `elements`, but `elements` is a pointer to *uninitialzed* memory. That cannot be (error!).

Now you test `if (argc != 2)` so `argv[1]` apparently should hold the number elements. Then you must first convert that to an int, use it to allocate that number of elements. Then you can call your `compute_fibs` function.

So probably you want something like:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int elements;
    unsigned long *fibs;

    if (argc != 2){
        printf("Usage: %s <# of elements>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }
    elements= atoi(argv[1]);
    fibs = malloc(elements*sizeof(*fibs));  // See Chux's comment

    compute_fibs (fibs, elements);

    for (i=0; i<elements; i++) {
        printf ("fibs[%i]: %lu\n",i, fibs[i]);
    }
    printf("Displaying %u fibs\n", elements);
}
```

Comment: Why `sizeof(long)` vs. `sizeof(unsigned long)` to match `unsigned long *fibs`, or perhaps even better `fibs = malloc(sizeof *fibs * elements)` and avoid type discrepancies?

Comment: @Chux, makes no difference. Your last proposal is best.

Comment: As a very minor point, I prefer to use `sizeof *ptr * n` vs. `n * sizeof *ptr` for consistency with `sizeof *ptr * n * m` where `m,n` might be `int` and then the order of multiplication is important.